# Unable to encrypt packet data using DES cbc encryption

Tags: openssl

I am implementing *Ipsec pipeline* for my small project, where I am supposed to encrypt incoming packet from network from Ip header onwards (tunnel mode of IPSEC).

My question is, can the `DES_ncbc_encrypt()` api of `openssl` can be used to encrypt the entire payload in one go or I am supposed to call the above api everytime with 64 bit of input at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The source code for `DES_ncbc_encrypt()` loops backwards from the length you specify, encrypting blocks of 8 bytes on it's own; it should encrypt everything in one call:

From ncbc_enc.c in des from OpenSSL:

```
for (l-=8; l>=0; l-=8)
            {
            c2l(in,tin0);
            c2l(in,tin1);
            tin0^=tout0; tin[0]=tin0;
            tin1^=tout1; tin[1]=tin1;
            DES_encrypt1((DES_LONG *)tin,_schedule,DES_ENCRYPT);
            tout0=tin[0]; l2c(tout0,out);
            tout1=tin[1]; l2c(tout1,out);
            }
        if (l != -8)
            {
            c2ln(in,tin0,tin1,l+8);
            tin0^=tout0; tin[0]=tin0;
            tin1^=tout1; tin[1]=tin1;
            DES_encrypt1((DES_LONG *)tin,_schedule,DES_ENCRYPT);
            tout0=tin[0]; l2c(tout0,out);
            tout1=tin[1]; l2c(tout1,out);
            }
```

Can you show some code?  What error are you getting?

Most of the OpenSSL encryption/decryption functions advocate use of the higher level EVP routines - have you tried that?  See [the EVP docs here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html#).